# How to add multiple class name at facebook developer console of android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

Hello I am working on android app where I have integrated facebook at two places. First is in `Invite` fragment and second is in another activity.

I want to know that for the `Invite` fragment, Do I have to add that fragment name or activity class name on which it is attached in the class name of facebook developer console.

Is there any way to add multiple class name there ? If so how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no way to add multiple class names. Secondly, you only need to add the class name if you're implementing the deep linking feature, you don't need to add it otherwise.

Comment: @MingLi I'm just using facebook SDK to post something on own user wall for that I have to submit app to facebook for review. There it is asking to me and that is mandatory field for review app. I'm not sure what deep linking you mean.

Comment: Then you can add any of your activities, preferably the main activity that your app starts with.

Comment: @MingLi Ok thanks, can you please answer so that i can accept your answer please. thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For login and app review, you can add any of your activities, like the main activity of your app.